# Trying to add more jQuery to my page but when I add in more link/script tags, the previous functioning jQuery ceases to run. Can somebody help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i had working?  ..................................................................

```
 <head>
 <title>#</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="sss/sss.min.js"></script>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="sss/sss.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="sss/sss.css" type="text/css" media="all">

 <script>
 jQuery(function($) {
 $('.slider').sss();
 });
 </script> 
</head>
```

What is not working?,...................................................

```
   <head>
   <title>#</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="sss/sss.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sss/sss.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
  $('.slider').sss();
  });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Why you need more than one `jQuery` on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't load multiple jquery versions.  Pick the one you need and just use that.  Multiple versions cannot coexist on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery.noconflict.
[jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Example from jquery doc:

Head

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Body

```
<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

// Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
// (the newer version)

jq162 = jQuery.noConflict( true );

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): " + jq162.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script>
```